# When using fetch how to convert response body from application/x-ndjson to application/json?

Tags: json, fetch, ndjson

I'm trying out Lichess API. I'm trying to export games of a user.
According to [documentation](https://lichess.org/api#operation/apiGamesUser) I can receive either PGN or ndjson as response.

Right now this don't work:

```js
const api_url = "https://lichess.org/api/games/user/Terinieks?max=5&since=1578607200000&perfType=bullet"

async function getData() {
   let response = await fetch(api_url, {
      headers: {
         "Accept": "application/x-ndjson"
      }
   });
   let data = await response.json();
}
getData()
```

I'm struggling to find how to make `await response.json()` work.

Since as far as I understand I now need somehow convert my response (which is in ndjson) into json, but how?

## Update 1

I'm trying to use [NPM package 'can-ndjson-stream'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/can-ndjson-stream), which was suggested from article: [Streaming Data with Fetch() and NDJSON](https://davidwalsh.name/streaming-data-fetch-ndjson)

In app.js I have `import ndjsonStream from "can-ndjson-stream";` but I get error:

```
module "c:/Users/Juris/Desktop/Chess Stats/node_modules/can-ndjson-stream/can-ndjson-stream"

Could not find a declaration file for module 'can-ndjson-stream'.
'c:/Users/Juris/Desktop/Chess Stats/node_modules/can-ndjson-stream/
can-ndjson-stream.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

  Try npm install @types/can-ndjson-stream if it exists 
or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing
declare module 'can-ndjson-stream';ts(7016)
```

And in Chrome this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "can-ndjson-stream". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

index.html has `<script type="module" src="JS/app.js"></script>`

Not sure how to get import statement work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As ndjson is in fact a collection of JSON lines, so, separated by `\n` characters, you should be able to get the results by changing this line:

```
let data = await response.json();
```

to:

```
let data = (await response.text()).match(/.+/g).map(JSON.parse);
```

NB: `/.+/g` matches non-empty lines.